# Ocultar parametros de banco de dados em Python

Tags: mysql, python, banco-de-dados, senhas

eu fiz um projeto que faz algumas verificações no banco de dados, mas eu estou passando o usuario e senha

```
try:
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'****', password='******', dsn = ****)
    print(con.version)
except:
    erroBD = False
    return erroBD
```

Mas eu sei que colocando usuario e a senha dessa maneira qualquer pessoa que tiver acesso ao codigo conseguira acessar ao banco de dados, eu quero saber se tem alguma forma de "ocultar" esses parametros.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/). Ele pode usar um arquivo de configuração `.env` ou variáveis de ambiente.  Existem outras bibliotecas para o mesmo fim.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar um arquivo `.env` para passar as credenciais, e se estiver utilizando um sistema operacional do tipo Linux (Ubuntu por exemplo), é bem simples:

Abra o terminal na pasta onde está seu script `.py` e digite:

```
touch .env
```

Isto ira criar o arquivo `.env`.

Então abra em um editor de código esse arquivo, pode ser o nano por exemplo, digitando no terminal:

```
nano .env
```

entao escreva suas credenciais dentro desse arquivo, no modelo:

```
MINHAVARIAVELDEUSUARIO='usuario'
MINHAVARIAVELDESENHA='senha'
MINHAVARIAVELDSN='dsn'
```

então no seu script voce pode utilizar uma lib chamada `dotenv`

intale-a com o pip

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

entao no seu script importe a lib e chame a função `load_dotenv()` e utilize a lib `os` para chamar as variaveis

vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv


load_dotenv()


CREDENTIALS = {
'user' : os.getenv('MINHAVARIAVELDEUSUARIO'),
'password' : os.getenv('MINHAVARIAVELDESENHA'),
'dsn' : os.getenv('MINHAVARIAVELDSN')
}



try:
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(user=CREDENTIALS.os.get('user'), 
        password=CREDENTIALS.os.get('password'), 
        dsn =CREDENTIALS.os.get('dsn')
    )
    
    print(con.version)

except:

    erroBD = False
    
    return erroBD
```

Lembrando que o arquivo `.env` deve ficar no mesmo nivel de diretorio do seu script `.py` , e tambem que no Windows basta voce criar um arquivo de texto com um bloco de notas e nomea-lo de ".env"

Os arquivos `.env` geralmente ficam ocultos no sistema, então habilite a opção de ver arquivos ocultos no seu computador.

Nas boas práticas deveria haver um script de configuração `.py` separado deste principal, porem é só uma boa pratica.